# How to cluster longitudinal data with varying time range?

Tags: clustering, panel-data

Are there any methods or algorithms to cluster longitudinal data where each subject may have different time range? For instance, subject A has observations from time 1 to 5, subject B has observations from time 1 to 7, subject C has observations from time 1 to 8 and so on.

Comment: Survival analysis, maybe

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am more interested in the clustering though, where I can see if there are groups of people that have similar trend of outcome throughout time.

Comment: Hi Can you elaborate as to at what level you want to cluster.What you have here is unbalanced panel data, but clustering shouldnot differ due that.

Comment: The flexmix package in R allows to fit mixtures of all kinds of (generalised) linear models; it maybe that it allows for this task. Have a look at the vignettes. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You could either

- Determine a function or set of function to map the longitudinal data to a fixed size.  For example, take the mean, max, min, sum, count of a time series.  Then, concatenate those values into vectors and cluster the vectors.
- Learn an [embedding](http://embedding) that represents the time series, which is similar to the first method except you learn the functions that are used to produce the vector representation, and then cluster the embeddings.  To create this embedding you could use a time series model that handles variable-length input (e.g., an RNN).

Answer (score 1):

See the `curveRep` function in the R `Hmisc` package exemplified [here](https://hbiostat.org/rflow/descript.html#longitudinal-continuous-y).  It clusters on the number of observations per subject, the longest time gap between any two measurements per subject, and the shape of the trajectories.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered growth mixture modeling (GMM)? GMM is a type of finite mixture modeling that identifies distinct subgroups of trajectories within longitudinal data. It can accommodate varying time points by estimating different growth parameters (e.g., intercepts and slopes) for each subgroup.